# Unable to run a python script using symfony process

Tags: php, laravel, process

I'm trying to call a python script from inside a php (laravel) function. When I call it nothing happens though. No output, no anything.

```
$commandline = "python " . base_path(). "\public\GiftScript\gift.py";
$process = new Process($commandline);
//var_dump($process);
$process->start();
echo $process->getOutput();
```

I would like for it to call the command without waiting for the output. Just create a new process and let it finish  running.